# ICS taskManager like animation [Slide right and left]

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to make an application (for homework),i spent 3 days looking for making an animation that looks like the ICS taskManger,my activity shows a lot of images verticaly,when i swipe right or left, the image should disappear

i tried with a lot of solutions but i never get the right one,please help me,
and thanks in advance

Comment: What's the best solution you've got so far, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: i tried with viewfliper but the slide doesn't folow my finger,
and for the viewFliper i found out thant is not a good way,
i tried also with "startDrag"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one of my solutions:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
final int action = event.getAction();
final float x = event.getX();
final float y = event.getY();
switch (action) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
{
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
View.DragShadowBuilder dsb = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
v.startDrag(clipData, dsb, v, 0);
v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


 }
return false;
                    }
```